# Can a Cordova/Phonegap app in the iOS app store reference hosted assets?

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store

I'm building an app that will only have index.html in it's root - the minified javascript and CSS will be loaded from S3 to make deployments easier. I know that Apple don't like apps that are simply a webview that loads a URL, but this will actually be a local view, but almost everything will load remotely. The app does have native functionality through Cordova plugins.

Comment: Yes, it can. But you should at least make the app "work" offline. By work I mean, show a message telling the user that the app need an internet connection

Comment: As above, just make sure that it **looks** like an app when the internet isn't working.